# Obtaining residuals from regressions with different sized columns

Tags: r, loops, matrix, regression

I am new to R and Statistics.

I have a matrix containing stock returns for 277 companies, the matrix contains 370 rows. Since these companies differ in age there are differences in the amounts of observations in the columns. I also have a matrix containing the Fama French factors and a vector containing a dummy variable. I have managed to create a loop for obtaining the coefficients of the regressions however i need to retrieve a matrix containing the residuals of the regressions, or a covariance matrix of the residuals so that i can perform a GRS test.

the code that I have used so far is:

```
reg <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=370, ncol=277))
for (i in c(1:277)) {
reg[,i] <- dynlm(returns.ts[,i] ~ 1 + Mkt.Rf + SMB + HML)$residuals
}
```

However when i run this loop i get an "replacement has 202 rows, data has 370" error. I am assuming that this is because of the differences in column lengths as the first two columns (belonging to companies with "full" observations) are filled in the return matrix.

I have tried na.action = na.omit with no success. Is there a way of filling this matrix with the residuals from these regressions? or possibly is it possible to obtain a covariance matrix circumventing this step? I am using R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list instead of a data.frame to store the residuals.

```
reg <- list()

for (i in c(1:277)) {
  reg[[i]] <- dynlm(returns.ts[,i] ~ 1 + Mkt.Rf + SMB + HML)$residuals
}
```

You can access the residuals using the same extraction method. For example, `reg[[1]]` will return the first set of residuals.

Comment: Sure thing, @Patrick Bukowsky. If this was helpful, you could select it as the answer (and maybe add an upvote).